# Refreshing App access token manually or using javascript code?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i have an app access token and suddenly i started getting errors that the

> The user must be an administrator of the page in order to
>   impersonate it.

I checked my access token using this

> https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token_info?client_id=935240123456789&access_token=XYyY1s9sxxRw09C1jm0nUwNdoAG

and it gives me an error

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid OAuth access token.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 190,
      "fbtrace_id": "CrmjdiD4HOR"
   }
}
```

Can you please guide me how can i generate a new refreshed access token to make the app functional again.
(Access token and appId changed as for security reasons).
I have gone through the developer.facebook.com but could not figure out any easy and clear solution as per my understanding of Javascript.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: those links describe how to generate an access token.

Comment: You presumably don’t mean an _app_ access token, but a user or page access token (go read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens, if the difference is not clear.) As for generating one - depends, do you want to implement full login (then do so, this is also described in quite a lot of detail), or do you just want to get one once for testing (then you could simply go use Graph API Explorer to generate/request one.)